# Copy an embedded structure into a new structure without having to copy all its fields

Tags: go

I have a struct that I use in my logic

```
type MyStruct struct {
  F1 string
  F2 string
}
```

I want to save values of type `MyStruct` to a document db, adding just a timestamp. So I create a new struct embedding `MyStruct`

```
type MyStructForDB {
  MyStruct
  Ts         time.Time
}
```

In the saveToDb function I do the following

```
func saveToDb(s MyStruct) {
  sDb := MyStructForDB{
    s, time.Now()
  }
  // execute the update on the DB
}
```

If I proceed like this, on the DB I find a document with the following structure

```
{
  myStruct: {
    f1: "a value"        // any value that was in s.F1
    f2: "another value"  // any value that was in s.F2
  }
  ts: 2020-06-26T14:15:07.050Z  // a timestamp value
}
```

While this is ok, I would prefer not to see the `myStruct` property but rather a flatter document like this

```
{
   f1: "a value"        // any value that was in s.F1
   f2: "another value"  // any value that was in s.F2
   ts: 2020-06-26T14:15:07.050Z  // a timestamp value
}
```

I understand I could do this copying one by one the fields or using reflection, but I was just wondering if there is simpler way to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DocumentDB, you can use `inline` flag of  `bson` package to flatten the embedded struct

```
type MyStructForDB {
  MyStruct   `bson:",inline"`
  Ts         time.Time
}
```